# how do i find out an outlook mail item id number?

Tags: javascript, vba, outlook

I am writing a VBscript to check on email items queued up, but i am wondering if they have an ID number or something like that, which is unique to each mail item.

My question is, if they do.  How do I expose/access it.

Comment: The closest is [EntryId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458.aspx) but read the caveats about moving messages

Answer (score 0):

MailItem.EntryID property.
Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815908.aspx